# apache 2.2 + mod_pagespeed + varnish

Tags: 7, caching

Did anyone try the combination Drupal 7 + apache 2.2 + mod_pagespeed + varnish?

Does it produce any problem?

IS Drupal own CSS and JavaScript aggregation mechanism needed if mod_pagespeed is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have yet to test it out. I do know that domain specific code CAN be better in comparison to a generalized tool like [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_mod.html); but I would imagine it would take a lot of effort to beat mod_pagespeed. mod_pagespeed should bring an improvement in comparison to drupal's core aggregation; you will get CSS & JS Compression among some other nice things.

In Drupal land we are working on improving the page load time. Here are some projects for that.

- http://drupal.org/project/wpo
- http://drupal.org/project/bundlecache
- http://drupal.org/project/advagg
- http://drupal.org/project/css_emimage
- http://drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize
- http://drupal.org/project/closure_compiler
- http://drupal.org/project/cdn

Long story short: Use mod_pagespeed today; checkout some of these projects in the future.

Comment: if i use mod_pagespeed and varnish should i turn off any of drupal cache or aggregation settings at performance?

Comment: Do not have drupal 7 versions: bundlecache, advagg,closure_compiler. cdn does not work always as expected. ImageAPI Optimize looks useful. wpo does not exist yet

Comment: Keep the Drupal cache set to external if using varnish. Aggregation is a little tricky; I would say turn it off, but I would be sure to test it. Once advagg 7.x gets a stable release I would use that and turn off mod_pagespeed's CSS/JS file aggregation (I'm the maintainer of advagg if you where wondering, so I will be a little biased).

Comment: thanks but there is no "external" cache settings in drupal 7. i think i had seen that in pressflow (based on drupal 6)

Comment: by the way, how I can instruct drupal to load javascript in the end, and which js files should be necessarily be loaded in the beginning?

Comment: looks like prepping for varnish is done in settings.php [drupal-7-varnish](http://blogs.osuosl.org/gchaix/2011/01/05/drupal-7-varnish/).

For JS loading issues advagg will give you the power to move them around; right now I would look at [labjs](http://drupal.org/project/labjs).

Comment: thanks for the link. i think an even better link is at http://swearingatcomputers.blogspot.com/2011/05/complete-drupal-cache-serving-http-and.html. i just give it for reference reasons. about labjs drupal module: i think it is not as actively developed as the headjs one. labjs modules still did not update since march, whereas headjs module updates daily

Comment: Hey they got a d7 version out for [headjs](http://drupal.org/project/headjs)! Sounds like you have a fairly good idea on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Varnish won't work properly if mod_pagespeed is enabled. I tested, if mod_pagespeed enabled, Varnish stop caching anything.

For reference: http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=232#c4

Comment: mod_pagespeed works just fine with Varnish and any other upstream cache or CDN: all of the static assets are cache-extended. For the base HTML file, if you have your own purge strategy, or are willing to live with some stale TTL, then you can turn off the cache stripping (on rewritten HTML): https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/install#ModifyCachingHeaders